# Appcelerator - Checking which textfield has focus

Tags: toolbar, appcelerator

I have a keyboard toolbar setup with a PREVIOUS and NEXT button. I'm trying to figure out which textfield has focus so I can allow the user to jump to the next field or go back to the previous field. My code currently looks like this:

```
//Setup keyboard toolbar.
var flexSpace = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
});

var navButtons = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({
    labels:['Previous','Next'],
    backgroundColor:'#336699',
    top:100,
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BAR,
    height:25,
    width:'auto'
});

navButtons.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // Previous Button, index 0.
    Titanium.API.info(e.index);
    if (e.index == 0){
        if (nameTxt.hasFocus == "nameTxt"){
            phoneTxt.focus();
        }
    }

    // Next Button, index 1.
    if (e.index == 1){
        if (nameTxt.hasFocus){
            nameTxt.hasFocus = false;
            phoneTxt.hasFocus = true;
        }/*else{
            done.fireEvent('click');
        }*/
    }

});
```

I think I'm close to getting this working, so just need the final push. Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

you could just set the keyboard to have a next button on it?

it won't solve the forward and back, but it is easier than the solution below.

The hard way is to track which field has focus in a separate property. Whenever the focus changes, update the property to the new item that has focus

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using addEventListener with blur and focus?
https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TextField-object

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from here:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120797/textfield---how-to-check-the-focus

```
function CreateTextField(options) {
    var tf = Ti.UI.createTextField(options);
    //define flag
    tf.hasFocus = false;

    tf.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        this.hasFocus = true;
    });

    tf.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        this.hasFocus = false;
    });
    return tf;
}
```

And then just call the CreateTextField like:

```
email=CreateTextField({
          width: 150,
          left: 110,
          height: 35,
          hintText: 'login_email',
          borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_NONE,
          keyboardType : Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_EMAIL,
          keyboardToolbar : [navButtons, flexSpace, done],
          color: '#949495'
        })
```

After that, you can do:

```
Titanium.API.info(email.hasFocus);

if (e.index == 0){
  if (email.hasFocus){
    email.focus();
  }
}
```

Hope this help you!